Calculating Betas of Univariate and Multivariate Linear Regression
I'm studying for an interview regarding statistics and regression and was wondering if anyone has ideas of resources to help study.
Example problems are:
Suppose we have an $n \times 1$ vector $y$ and an $n \times p$ matrix $X$, where each column of $X$ has mean $0$. For each column of $X$, if we do univariate linear regression of $y$ against that column, we get a positive beta. Now suppose we do multivariate regression of the whole matrix $X$ against $y$, and we get a $p \times 1$ beta vector. Prove or disprove: at least one of the coefficients in the multivariate regression must be positive.
So far, all I really know is that in regression, we can calculate the coefficients of regression according to $$w = (X^TX)^{-1} X^T y$$
but I don't see how that would help with figuring out if any values are positive/negative. Where does the assumption that each column of X has mean $0$ come into play?
First of all, are the coefficients of this $w$ vector even the "beta" coefficients in question? Are there more applicable formulas for actually calculating these coefficients?

What immediately comes to mind is Simpson's paradox. Even if x1..xn all positively impact y independently, when put together, they might cause impact in the opposite direction.

But also, currently, I'm more interested in knowing if there are any other formulas out there for beta coefficients. I feel that there must be something regarding covariances or correlations that feels more statistical in nature as compared to this big matrix formula.

You're making it too complicated.For Simpson's paradox you need to have different subpopulations, but we don't need that to come up with an example. We just need $x_2$ to proxy for $x_1$ strongly enough that it looks like $x_2$ has a positive effect even though it has a negative effect.

but how do correlations and covariances and effect sizes affect beta coefficients? In the matrix formula that I put above, there is no mention of them. are there alternative beta formulas/representations that take correlation and covariance of x1, x2 into account?

Because the columns have $0$ mean, $X^T X$ is the covariance matrix of the $x_i$, and $X^T y$ is the vector of covariances between the $x_i$ and $y$ (except not divided by $n-1$),

@mathz2003 Do you mean $\beta$ (beta) instead of w at $w = (X^TX)^{-1} X^T y$? It confuses me.

yes beta and w are the same here.

The formula for the univariate regression coefficient is
$$\hat{\beta} = \frac{\hat{cov}(X,Y)}{\hat{var}(X)}$$
Where $\hat{cov}$ denotes the sample covariance between random variables $X$ and $Y$. So $\hat{\beta} >0$ iff the covariance is positive.
Because you're told the columns of $X$ have mean $0$, $X^T y$ is the vector of sample covariances, except not divided by $n-1$, so essentially what you've been told is $X^T y$ is a vector of positive numbers.
Similarly, $X^T X$ is the covariance matrix of all the $X_i$, multiplied by $n-1$, so it must be positive semidefinite. So another way of phrasing your question is 'can we find a positive semidefinite matrix $M$ and a vector $w$ which is all negative such that $Mw = v$ is all positive?'.
The answer to this is no, because if we multiply both sides by $w^T$ we have
$$w^T M w = w^T v < 0$$
which contradicts that $M$ is positive semidefinite.
